# Can you use Immutable fromJS() on an object that already partially contains Immutable objects?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have a plain javascript object that I want to convert to an immutable Map using "fromJS()". However, I want one of my fields, the `Supplier.selectedIndices` to be a `Set()`. By default, fromJS() converts that to a `List()`. Can I do the following where in my plain Javascript object, I initiate a `Set()` object?

Is this good practice? Please advise. Thanks!

```
export const initialState = fromJS({
  Inventory: {
    inventory: [],
    selectedInventory: [],
  },
  Supplier: {
    suppliers: [],
    selectedIndices: Set(),
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the title, using `fromJS` on mixed objects is safe. The [docs sort of mention that](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS):

> fromJS is conservative in its conversion. It will only convert arrays which pass Array.isArray to Lists, and only raw objects (no custom prototype) to Map.

Immutable collections don't match those criteria.

To answer the body of your question, `fromJS` provides a `reviver`:

> If a reviver is optionally provided, it will be called with every collection as a Seq (beginning with the most nested collections and proceeding to the top-level collection itself), along with the key refering to each collection and the parent JS object provided as this. For the top level, object, the key will be "". This reviver is expected to return a new Immutable Collection, allowing for custom conversions from deep JS objects. Finally, a path is provided which is the sequence of keys to this value from the starting value.

The `reviver` function should be able to detect your field (either using the value type or the path provided by Immutable) and create a `Set`.